# pandas for loop with mysql query and variable parmeters

Tags: python, pandas

I was loading my data from individual csv files into a dataframe using

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', names=col_names, sep=',', skiprows=1)
col_names = ['created_date', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

This would separate my data nicely into column frames and skip the first row which had the row labels

However i wanted to automate the process using a for loop that did the same query for every user. My function goes:

```
sql = "select distinct mobile_user_id from score where speed_range_id > 1"
distance_query = """SELECT created_date, latitude, longitude FROM score s where s.mobile_user_id = %(mobile_user_id)s and speed_range_id > 1 group by latitude, longitude order by id asc"""
cursor1.execute(sql)
result = cursor1.fetchall()

for rowdict in result:
    distance = cursor3.execute(distance_query, rowdict)
    distance_result = cursor3.fetchall()
    df = pd.read_sql_query(distance_query, rdsConn, params={rowdict})
```

As you can see here the result variable holds the list of users and i want to iterate through all the users to generate a dataset for every user.

I've been trying to use the `pd.read_sql_query` but i've been unable to pass the mobile user parameter which is `rowdict` to the query.

How would i go so i can pass that variable using pandas? How can i organize my data in the way i had it before?

sample of the data.csv:

```
created_date,          latitude,    longitude
"2018-05-24 17:46:25", 20.61844841, -100.40813424
"2018-05-24 21:03:02", 20.58469452, -100.39204018
"2018-05-25 10:29:57", 20.61180308, -100.40826959
"2018-05-25 21:02:43", 20.59868518, -100.37825344
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @parfait sorry, that shouldn;t be there

Comment: I'm not understanding. Both queries run same `WHERE` condition: `speed_range_id > 1` from same table, `score`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running pure SQL combining both queries by adding a `WHERE` clause to your aggregate query.

Currently, you are attempting a `WHERE` clause comparing one value per row to many values: `where mobile_user_id = %(mobile_user_id)s` which will never be equal. Plus, your prepared statement does not have same number of placeholders as parameter values. Possibly you meant `where mobile_user_id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ...)` which involves dynamically setting placeholders, `?`.

Nonetheless, simply run an aggregate query. Then, import the resultset into pandas. Specifically, add *mobile_user_id* as a grouping in query:

```
sql = """select mobile_user_id, created_date, latitude, longitude
         from score
         where speed_range_id > 1
         group by mobile_user_id, created_date, latitude, longitude 
         order by id asc
      """

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, rdsConn)
```